# How can I send data from a Node.js application hosted on Heroku to a PHP file hosted on a completely separate (Cpanel) server?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, heroku, cpanel

I can't seem to find a good answer to this question anywhere after searching for over 30 minutes. I hope this hasn't been asked already.

So, I want to build an online game. It will be a very simple online game (mostly for practice). I want to host this game on Heroku, and I will code the game using Node.js. Now, I have a separate server (a shared server running Apache and Cpanel) where I will want to store all the permanent data for the game (in a MySQL database). So what I need to do is serve up the game using PHP on my Apache web server, allow users to create accounts/sign into accounts on the Apache server (using a MySQL database also located there), then I want them to be able to "join a room" and when they do that, I want to send them off to the Node.js server running on Heroku, and allow that server to handle everything related to gameplay (through WebSockets). Now, after they're finished with their game, I want to save their scores and some other related data about them into my MySQL database over on my Apache server... Is there a way I can do this? Is there any means by which I can send data from a Node.js server running on Heroku to a PHP file on my Apache server? (For example, handlepostgame.php or something similar)

I hope this is a clearly written question and that you're able to easily understand what I'm asking. If not, let me know and I'll try to make it more clear! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `there any means by which I can send data from a Node.js server running on Heroku to a PHP file on my Apache server`...yes, just make it send a HTTP request

Comment: Oh okay I'll look into that! I couldn't seem to find anywhere on the internet that showed how to do that using Node.js, but now that I know exactly what to look for I'll go spend some more time searching and see what I can find. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @ADyson for pointing me in the right direction!

So, I found the answer that suits my needs! This is my "requesttophp.js" file: (Node.js)

```
var http = require('http');

console.log("running");

var query = "something=cookie";
var queryLength = query.length;

var options = {
  host: 'www.mydomain.com',
  path: '/path/to/fromnodejs.php',
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': queryLength
  }
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.write(query);
req.end();
```

respondtonodejs.php: (PHP)

```
<?php

echo "it worked\n";
echo $_POST["something"];

?>
```

The result is

```
running
it worked
cookie
```

It does exactly what I want! :) Thank you.